# Why get i InputMismatchException when i use scanner sc.nextDouble()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

I'd like to read data from a `txt` file, but I get `InputMismatchException` when I call `nextDouble()` method. Even though I am using the `useLocale` method, but it doesn't work.

The txt file first line is: `1;forname;1.9`

```
public class SimpleFileReader {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        readFromFile();
    }
    public static void readFromFile(){
        try {
            int x = 0;
            File file = new File("read.txt");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter(";|\\n");
            sc.useLocale(Locale.FRENCH);
            while (sc.hasNext()){
                System.out.println(sc.nextInt()+" "+sc.next()+" "+sc.nextDouble());
                x++;
            }
            System.out.println("lines: "+x);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blame the French locale: it uses comma as a decimal separator, so `1.9` fails to parse.

Replacing `1.9` with `1,9` fixes the problem ([demo 1](http://ideone.com/IusD9m)). If you would like to parse `1.9`, use `Locale.US` instead of `Locale.FRENCH` ([demo 2](http://ideone.com/YPLvLu)).

A second problem in your code is the use of `\\n` as the separator. You should use a single backslash, otherwise words that contain `n` would break your parsing logic.

Comment: I'd like to use a decimal point instead of a comma and i've rewritten this code useLocale(Locale.US) and i tried Locale.ENGLISH , but none of them work.

Comment: @Bbeni It's a different problem - you get an exception on a line that has an `n`. Please see the edit.

Comment: The txt file was wrong. I had to replace the end of line characters from \r to \n. It's working now. Thank you for help